# Possible for Instruments to show Leaks on autoreleased objects?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch

I'm having a difficult time understanding where actual Leaks are happening and where they are not in my application using Instruments. I have objects which are autoreleased and not being retained afterwards.. that are showing up as leaks via Instruments. There's also a bunch of objects which are listed as leaking that don't point back to any code that I've written myself. Perhaps it's a domino effect where one of my real leaks is causing stuff within the Apple libraries to leak, but I'm reluctant to believe that is the case. What's the best way of differentiating where the real leaks are happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my experience Instruments does not give false-positives for auto-released items. (these are still referenced by an auto-release pool so there's no magic difference).

With memory leaks there can indeed by a domino effect in that one culprit results in many cascading leaks. Within instruments each leak will have a time based identity so I suggest you start with the first leaks.